# How to add multi nodes on a single page without using an iFrame?

Tags: 7, nodes

I came up with the [Multi Node Add](https://www.drupal.org/project/multi_node_add) module to add multiple nodes to single page. But the nodes are shown on iframe.

Is there another way with which we can add multiple node on single page without iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, to insert a message with a clickable link in the Drupal Message area, whereas that link points to "/node/add" each time a node is saved.

Here is a summary of the rule to implement this:

**Events**: After saving new content

**Actions**: Show a message on the site, whereas the "value" of the message to be displayed should be something like so: `<a href="[site:url]/node/add">Click</a> to add another node.`

This assumes you want to do this for all possible content types. If you'd want to limit it to specific types only, you'd have to add appropriate
**Conditions** (for the desired content types) also.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Advanced Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb):

> Welcome to Advanced Form Block Module. With this module you can do the
>   following:
>
> 1) Create any number of blocks with a particular node edit form. 2)
>   create any number of blocks with a particular node add form of a
>   content type. 3) Create as many blocks as you like of each kind. 4)
>   From the content type choose which fields to display on a per block
>   basis.However required fields will be automatically displayed. 5) All
>   forms will be saved through ajax. So multiple node forms can be
>   independently placed on a single page and worked with simultaneously.

With this, you can add any number of node add/edit forms (each with their own submit controls)